# I inherited a Magento project and can't seem to find this particular page?

Tags: magento

I took over an implementation of Magento Enterprise.

There is a URL that looks something like this:

mydomain.com/our-solutions

It's got a dynamic part to it; under the CMS tab in the Admin I don't see anything that matches that URL.

In the extended local files, I don't see anything in the config for it but it seems to know to load up a particular template.

I need to be able to modify the controller for this particular page. Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you find "our-solutions" in the list in _Admin > Catalog > URL Rewrite Management_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to temporarily add some debugging code to the following file

```
# File app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php

public function preDispatch()
{
    //log out the class name
    Mage::Log( get_class($this) );

    //or just dump it if you don't know how logging works
    var_dump(get_class($this));
    $this->getLayout()->setArea($this->_currentArea);

    parent::preDispatch();
    return $this;
}
```

This will let you discover which class file is the controller for the request, and you can code trace from there.

Also (shameless plug time) I build and sell [a commercial product](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug) that will (among other things) allow you to (among other things) instantly zero in on which controller, block, model, or collection  was used for a particular request.  There's a [demo page](http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/) you can checkout, and while it's clearly self-serving of me to mention it, I also truly believe it's the best way for a developer to work with Magento.